# Drupal and SSL on specific sections

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

How can I enable SSL (https) only on some pages of my Drupal website ?

Do I need to use modules, or should I configure it from hosting settings ?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the Secure Pages module: http://drupal.org/project/securepages